# Unable to connect to SQL Server from Windows Service running on Windows Web Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-services, windows-server-2008-r2

I am facing a following error while trying to connect with an SQL server from **Windows Service (written in vb.net)**.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

This service is running on a **Windows Web Server 2008 R2** and with **SQL Server 2008**. SQL Server is also located on the same machine. Also, the **firewall is disabled** on the server. I have couple of web applications running on the same **windows server** connecting to the same **sql server** and there is no connection issue. But, this issue is faced only when I try to connect from the **windows service only**.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is that a named instance ? IS SQL Browser service is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have 1 of the following problems.

You are not using the correct connection string. Dump out the string you are actually using from from your running service and make sure you can connect with it.

You have a permissions problem -- you should double check the security context the service is using. This is a common problem if you are trying to connect using integrated security, or user impersonation in particular.

ADDED

If you have intermittent problems, there is different problem. (unlikely based on your problem description.) The reason I suggest dumping the connection string from your service to make sure it is correct, is that so often the developer (including me) is SURE that it is correct, when it is not.

If you are using integrated security, the process runs using the security context of the service, and this the user context that will be used by the database -- look at service properities, you specify which user is used to run the service.

If using impersonation, you basically switch the security context to be that of the user -- this would normally be done if the website is using integrated security as well, i.e., not forms based security -- suitable for in-house use, not public facing websites.

Comment: Connection string is same which I am using in web application. It is correct. Also, service is enabled to run with the local admin rights.

Comment: Can you elaborate? 'This is a common problem if you are trying to connect using integrated security, or user impersonation in particular.'

Comment: Have you dumped the connection string to verify that it is actually correct? If not, I strongly recommend you do so. I I had a nickle ...

Comment: About security context, so I did everything. Ran it as a domain administrator, local administrator, local service, nothing helped. In the connection string I am supplying 'sa' and password, do you think I am still missing something? As I mentioned, the same connection string worked on the Web application.

Comment: Frankly, I don't believe you are using the correct connection string, because experience tells me this is almost always the problem and you have not said, YES I dumped (or otherwise verified) the connection string in the service is in fact correct. You simply state that it is correct because it is the same as you use elsewhere. You eliminate most of the other common problems (e.g., DNS problems, firewall issues, Database service not running) when you say it is running on the same machine and other processes are working

Comment: I am little confuse about verifying it or dumping it from windows service. This is my first experience with Windows apps(or service). So tell me how do i dump it or verify it?

Comment: Thanks, Finally, solved it. No doubt, Einstein is your look a like ;-)

Comment: I just like the frivolous side of the renouned scientist. I take it the connection string was not right? Yes?

Comment: Yes connection string was not right. I am little confused as why MS uses My.Settings.ConnectionString and ConnectionString as two different things in windows application. Former does not exist in the Web Applications.

Comment: I had a similar issue with c# windows service, after adding a reference to System.Configuration it worked like a charm